# CoffeeScript sourcemaps points to wrong files

Tags: coffeescript, source-maps, brunch

I'm building coffee-script project with brunch@1.7.14 and coffee-script-brunch@1.8, with all default settings.

Then I run a project and got an error somewhere in depths.

And when I'm looking to stacktrace, I see something like this:

```
module.exports.View.render          jquery.idle-timer.js:24
module.exports.View.afterInitialize jquery.center.js:51
instance.(anonymous function)       jquery.center.js:7
Backbone.View                       jquery-ui.js:1878
View                                jquery.center.js:23
```

What the madness is this?

It is expected that links on the right points to something like app/some/path/view.coffee, not to jquery plugins (which was not even used in this specific case).

How to fix it?

**Upd.**

This happens in Chrome and Safari.
I've already tried all `coffee-script` versions starting from `1.3.3`, and `coffee-script-brunch` starting from `1.4.0`. All that I have is a bit different line numbers in stacktrace - but they are still **wrong**.

What is even more interesting, on a test project with three modules all works perfect - stacktrace points to exactly a line which throws an error. On big project all is wrong. I don't understand how could this be.

**Upd.2**

Well, I've found that sourcemaps are compiled wrong.

When I build same project with same version of all packages on another computer and then just put sourcemaps, compiled there, to my computer - all works perfect.

As I noticed above, I've already tried to reinstall all packages which could be involved here. I even tried to reinstall Node.js, in simple way - `brew uninstall node`, `brew install node`. It didn't help.

So what else could be updated/reinstalled/cleaned/etc. to fix this issue?

**Upd.3**

Well... It seems to be a kind of magic. I've created a pure virtual machine with Ubuntu, cloned project there and build it. In absolutely pure environment.

With **same results**.

I don't know what the hell is going on, now I suppose that even if I'll reinstall OS, it will not help. Maybe, buying a new computer can solve the problem, I don't know...

Answer (score 2):

Unexpectedly, but I've found an answer.

The only reason was in [source-map package](https://www.npmjs.org/package/source-map), which is in `brunch` dependencies.

I've tried only two last versions of brunch: 1.7.13 and 1.7.14. Both of them requires `source-map` version `~0.1.26`. Which is for now resolved to `0.1.34` wherever you install brunch.

And this is a root of evil.

**What I've actually did is manual replace 0.1.34 with 0.1.33, directly in global `brunch/node_modules` folder.**

And that's it. After this everything magically fixed, and my sourcemaps point to right lines again.

Don't know WHY it is so - maybe, `source-map@0.1.34` is broken. But this really works.